# Z-index не работает на opacity

Tags: opacity, z-index, html, css

Есть

```
<div class="header">
<div class="logo">
</div>
</div>
```

это изображения, у header opacity 0.7 и z-index 1, а у logo не нужно вообще opacity и z-index 2, но все равно opacity накладывается и на logo.
Как побороть?

Comment: демку сделайте

Comment: ну поставьте опасити на лого 1

Answer (score 5):

Нельзя просто так взять и отменить прозрачность.

Давайте посмотрим на страницу в целом, не вдаваясь в детали типа логотипа. Вот у вас есть отдельный кусок страницы - шапка. Вы делаете ее полупрозрачной. Это значит, что вы делаете ее вместе со всем ее содержимым полупрозрачным, чего бы там не было. Если бы внутри можно было сделать что-нибудь обратно непрозрачным, то изначальное действие потеряло бы смысл.

Возращаясь обратно к деталям обратите внимание на то, что значение по умолчанию для прозрачности это 1. Выставляй не выставляй логотипу прозрачность 1, она все-равно будет свой честной единицей.

Возможно вам поможет полупрозрачный фон rgba(255,124,124, .7); или создать отдельный слой для того, что вы хотите сделать полупрозрачным, например:

```
<style>
    .background {
        background: url(pattern.jpg);
        opacity: .7;
    }
</style>
<div class="header">
    <div class="background"></div>

    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="contacts"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать свободно псевдо-классы блоков для реализации данной задачи. Пример

```
<pre>#header:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity:0.7;
    z-index:-1;
    background:url(../images/sprite.png) -482px 0;
    }</pre>
```

`z-index` положит `before` под остальные элементы в хедере. Если используется на картинка, а цвет, то можно свободно использовать `rgba`-цвета с каналом прозрачности

```
<pre>background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);</pre>
```

Comment: Я практически тоже самое написал чуть выше :) Только псевдо-элемент не использовал. И вам не рекоменду без острой необходимости типа сделать html-код чистым или, скажем, если у вас вообще доступа к html нет. Сиди потом, ищи как тут в шапке фон сделан )

Comment: Использование псевдо-элементов для стилизации вполне оправдывает себя. Они хорошо отображаются в инспекторе FF и Chrome. Так же они не входят в DOM, что снижает нагрузку. Ну и конечно же HTML чище с их использованием :)

Comment: >>Они хорошо отображаются в инспекторе FF и Chrome
Это когда знаешь, что они там есть :)

Comment: Я без проблем нахожу их. Если в стилях блока не видишь каких-либо свойств, но они применяются, то логично предположить, что не все так просто. Когда сам пишешь код, то ты в курсе всех фичей, а если ковырять что-то чужое, то там можно ногу сломать и без псевдо-элементов. В любом случае их использование лучше нагромождения лишнего HTML, который не несет в себе никакого контента